# how to use FileSystemWatcher using asp.net(C#)

Tags: asp.net

SENARIO: i have few folders on my FTP server, belongs to particular user. Suppose i have 10GB total space and i assign 1GB to each user i.e can accomodate 10 users having 1GB each.

now users can add/delete/edit any type of file to utilize the storage space. All i need to do is to restrict users not to exceed 1gb space for their file storage. For this i want to use FileSystemWatcher to notify me that a user had created/deleted/edited a file so that i can minimize the space from 1gb incase of creation of a file or add a space incase of deletion.

this is the piece of coding using FSW. when user gets loged-in with proper id and password, respective folder is opened (present at FTP server) where he can add/delete/edit any type of file and according to that i hav to monitor d space ulitilized by him.

but d problem is the event handlers (written in console). i dont understand what happens when this code is being runned... i dontknow how to use FSW class so that i can monitor d changes user is making in his folder.

please help ... THANX

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

public class _Default: System.Web.UI.Page {
    public class ClsFileSystemWatcher {
        public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("File "+e.FullPath+" :"+e.ChangeType);
        }

        public static void OnDeleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("File "+e.FullPath+" :"+e.ChangeType);
        }

        public static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("File "+e.FullPath+" :"+e.ChangeType);
        }

        public static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("File "+e.OldFullPath+" [Changed to] "+e.FullPath);
        }

        public static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error "+e);
        }

        public void FileWatcher(string InputDir) {
            using (FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher()) {
                fsw.Path = InputDir;
                fsw.Filter = @"*";
                fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName|NotifyFilters.Attributes|NotifyFilters.LastAccess|NotifyFilters.LastWrite|NotifyFilters.Security|NotifyFilters.Size|NotifyFilters.CreationTime|NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                fsw.Changed += OnChanged;
                fsw.Created += OnCreated;
                fsw.Deleted += OnDeleted;
                fsw.Renamed += OnRenamed;
                fsw.Error += OnError;
                fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                //string strOldFile = InputDir + "OldFile.txt";     
                //string strNewFile = InputDir + "CreatedFile.txt";    
                //// Making changes in existing file    
                //using (FileStream stream = File.Open(strOldFile, FileMode.Append))     
                //{     
                // StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);     
                // sw.Write("Appending new line in Old File");     
                // sw.Flush();     
                // sw.Close();     
                //}    
                //// Writing new file on FileSystem     
                //using (FileStream stream = File.Create(strNewFile))    
                //{    
                // StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);    
                // sw.Write("Writing First line into the File");    
                // sw.Flush();     
                // sw.Close();     
                //}    
                //File.Delete(strOldFile);     
                //File.Delete(strNewFile);     
                // Minimum time given to event handler to track new events raised by the filesystem.    
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private DAL conn;
    private string connection;
    private string id = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\project\\Desktop\\BE prj\\dbsan.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
        conn = new DAL(connection);
        ////*** Opening Respective Folder of a User ***////     
        DirectoryInfo directories = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Inetpub\\ftproot\\san\\");
        DirectoryInfo[] folderList = directories.GetDirectories();
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null) {
            id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        }
        string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\\Inetpub\\ftproot\\san\\", id);
        int folder_count = folderList.Length;
        for (int j = 0; j < folder_count; j++) {
            if (Convert.ToString(folderList[j]) == id) {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
                p.Start();
            }
        }
        ClsFileSystemWatcher FSysWatcher = new ClsFileSystemWatcher();
        FSysWatcher.FileWatcher(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using NTFS Disk Quotas? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781892(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Each time you reload the page you create new FSW - in that case you won't get any events raised, because from the point of newly created FSW nothing was changes. Try to preserve your FileSystemWatcher object in the Session state.

So flow would look like:

- User logs in – you create FSW and preserve it in Session
- User reloads the page – get FSW from Session (do not create new one)

Comment: if u dont mind then can u recode my coding it will be great help for me if u think this can work. plz .. THANX

Answer (score 0):

You should create a worker role (service) for this type of thing. I think it is not appropriate to have something like this inside of a page.

Comment: but question is how to create the service... ??? any example coding would be highly appreciated thanx

Comment: Yeah service would fit better here but IMHO you can use FSW in ASP.NET

Comment: An old article from CodeProject - How to implement a simple filewatcher Windows service in C# - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/C__FileWatcher.aspx